# could not deploy the maven because of this issue,how to resolve?

Tags: maven, dependency-management, artifact

> ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer
>   org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle-jaxrs:jar:2.7.5 from http:// 
>   repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,
>   resolution will not be reattempted until the update   interval of
>   central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not
>   transfer artifact org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle-  jaxrs:jar:2.7.5 from/to
>   central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received
>   after 60000

Answer (score 0):

> No response received after 60000.

Your maven client try to download the artifact from internet but failed. If you have connection with remote repository retry with -U parameter.

Ex.

```
mvn package -U
```

The -U parameter forces a check for updated releases and snapshots on remote repositories.